# Woocommerce Custom Orders

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce, woothemes

I am new to woocommerce plugin development. I am making a website for a taylor, in which it is required to have custom sizes for different shirts, etc. My question is that how could I add the custom functionality like this, in which customers could add their own sizes and we can receive their orders.

I have searched all over the internet but could not find the good resource which could solve my problem. For the reference I am uploading the following image of custom order page

[image]

Comment: The easiest way? Probably this plugin: http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/

Comment: Hi, did you able to find any?

Answer (score 0):

Are these measurements automatically incorporated in the price? or is your system just for taking orders online and the tailor replies with a custom price quote?

Easiest way is to just add this to the checkout process. 
http://www.globussoft.com/how-to-add-custom-field-on-woocommerce-checkout/